# xcdatamodel Contents Disappears

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, xcdatamodel

I've had this happen a few times.

The contents of proj.xcdatamodeld/proj.xcdatamodel/ randomly disappear off my hard drive. However, Xcode will open the model file just fine.

Sometimes all three files disappear (elements, layout, contents). Other times only a subset of the files disappear.

I've done a filesystem check with Disk Utility which detected no problems.

I've checked that all the build settings etc. for the xcdatamodel are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've figured out what the problem is.

The core data file is incompatible across Snow Leopard Xcode 4.0 and Lion Xcode 4.1.

Edit: You can fix this problem by clicking on .xcdatamodel, and in the right-hand panel under "Tools Version" minimum set it to "Xcode 3.2".

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps confusing `*.xcdatamodel` and `*.xcdatamodeld`?

What's the problem if everything works?

Comment: Contents of proj.xcdatamodeld/proj.xcdatamodel/

But it doesn't work. When I load it to the device the model file does not exist.

Comment: Perhaps any source control software (git, subversion) getting in the way?

Comment: Hm I suppose it's possible. I'll do some research.